# AWT-EventQueue-0 NullPointerException because of Graphics g initilisation

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, graphics2d

(I'm new here, sorry if I forget to write any important information).
I'm trying to visualise weather from the AccuWeather API and I am currently stuck with the initilisation of `Graphics g`, I think.

So this is my inilisation:

```
public class Draw extends JFrame {

    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Graphics g;
```

I tried `Graphics g = new Graphics();` but that doesn't work because `Graphics g` is static.

this is a part of my paint method:

```
public void paint (Double[] weather, String sender, Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        if (sender.equals("index5_Button")) {

            Graphics2D stargazing = (Graphics2D) g;
            ((Graphics2D) g).setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

this is what the call for paint looks like:

```
paint(weatherValue, sender, g);
```

So obviously it isn't initilising `g` correctly, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot for possible help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried Graphics g = new Graphics();

You should not be trying to initialize the `Graphics` object of a component. Swing will create the Graphics object and pass it to the component when the component is repainted.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a `JPanel`. Then you add the panel to the JFrame`.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // add custom painting logic here
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started. The tutorials will show you how to better structure your classes.